# Mono problems with cert and mozroots

Tags: .net, security, firefox, mono, ssl-certificate

I am using this command on my mono VM

```
sudo mozroots --import --sync
```

It appears to be getting the cert from [this site](http://lxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt).

I then try to connect to my ssl site and i get the exception that the cert is invalid. I use firefox and see the cert was issued in 2010. I looked at that file and see the last time its been updated was 2009-05-21 12:50

When using firefox on the same machine i can navigate to the same url i am trying to connect to and i get no ssl issues. (no alert nor asking me to add it to an exception).

I am confused here. How do i update mono to use the latest certs?

-edit- I checked who signed the cert of the site i want to visit and their name is in certdata. I wonder why mono says the cert is not valid.

---

I tried writing this and i hit yes to the 3 cert it asked me to import

```
certmgr -ssl https://www.site.com/users/login --machine
```

I ran my application again and got this error. Googling the error code 0xffffffff80092012 i [found this](http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-bugs@lists.ximian.com/msg74638.html).

Looks like a fixed bug that hasnt been applied to 2.6.4. Or i could be doing it wrong. I do set the ServerCertificateValidationCallback to my own thing and return true for this application as a fix for mono.

> System.Net.WebException: Error getting
>   response stream (Write: The
>   authentication or decryption has
>   failed.): SendFailure --->
>   System.IO.IOException: The
>   authentication or decryption has
>   failed. --->
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException:
>   Invalid certificate received from
>   server. Error code: 0xffffffff80092012

Answer (score 3):

Follow-up about bug 606002 - here is the code to ignore said error code. Call it once in your initialization

```
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) {
                foreach (X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus) {
                    if (status.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

1. A default installation of Mono doesn't trust anyone!
2. [mozroots](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/mozroots.1.html) will download and import trusted root certificates from [Mozilla's LXR](http://lxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt).
3. Read the [Mono Security FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security)

EDIT:

- Try the latest version of Mono packages from [here](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)
- If that doesn't work either try the SVN trunk version [here](http://mono.ximian.com/monobuild/snapshot/download-trunk/)
- From the [Bug 606002](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=606002#c1), Gonzalo Paniagua Javier' suggested:  "The way to go is to add your ServerCertificateValidationCallback to ServicePointManager and ignore errors with this code."
- I have little experience in this area so I suggest to contact him for further assistance, maybe he can help. He's email is gonzalo@gonzalo.name ([his blog](http://gonzalo.name/blog/))