# quickbooks api v3 IdsQuery

Tags: c#, api, mono, quickbooks

I have inherited an app which uses `quickbooks` api v2 with php and things work just fine.

Over the last couple weeks I have been tasked with moving from api v2 to api v3 due to the "harmony" migration.   I have done this migration using the .Net version of `quickbooks` api v3 and everything has worked well in my development environment but when I pushed my changes to my staging server it does not work.  The oath portion works fine.  I am redirected to the intuit website to confirm my authorization that my app should be given access to my `quickbooks` information.  Everything works well until I am redirected to my `oath_callback_url` where I actually do a query for `TaxCodes` in `quickbooks` to see what `TaxCodes` are available for my particular user.

The code I am referring to is as follows:

```
QueryService<TaxCode> taxCodeQueryService = new QueryService<TaxCode>(getServiceContext(RestProfile.GetRestProfile()));
taxCodes = taxCodeQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * From TaxCode").ToList<TaxCode>();
```

With this code, I receive an error that says:

> Message: There was an error while communicating with the Ids Server
>   InnerException Message: The Response Stream was null or empty.

Basically, I am making a query for `TaxCodes` and sending it to the intuit servers but I am getting nothing back (after a good 30 second wait).  Everything works fine in my development environment but when I deploy to the staging server this problem occurs.  I have checked all kinds of firewall situations on this server but I am unable to get a valid result back from intuit's server.  I have tried a query of `TaxCodes` as well as just a general query of a `Customer` list.  I get the same result.

On my staging server I am using `mono 3.4.0` just as I am in my development environment.  Everything works perfectly in development but on my server I get the timeout/no response from intuit.

If you have an explanation or a suggestion for how to relieve the problem, I am appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer here in case anyone else has this problem.

The problem has to do with deploying the app on linux.  Mono on linux does not come with a set of trusted root certificates so I imported them with the mozroots utility that comes with mono.  That apparently is not sufficient when working with the ssl certificate provided by the quickbooks api server.  You either need to trust the correct root certificate or use one of the fixes provided here: [Mono problems with cert and mozroots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285489/mono-problems-with-cert-and-mozroots)